# Setting the font size with Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages, client-side, font-size

On the `MasterPage.Master` i set the the font size in my webpage   <`body  onload="checkCookie()">`

```
<div id="menu">
       <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:decFontSize();" class="minus"></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:defaultFontSize();" class="default"></a></li> 
            <li><a href="javascript:incFontSize();" class="plus"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and here is the associated Javascript

```
var min = 11;
var max = 18;

function checkCookie(){
var FontSize=getCookie('FontSize');
if (FontSize!=null && FontSize!="")
  {var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
      for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) 
      {p[i].style.fontSize = FontSize + "px"}}
  else {
      {
          var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
          for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
          { p[i].style.fontSize = FontSize + "px" } 
      }
    setCookie('FontSize', 13, 365);
  }
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) c_end = document.cookie.length
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return ""
}

function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + expiredays);
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
}

function defaultFontSize() {
        var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
        for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
        { p[i].style.fontSize = 13 + "px" }
        setCookie('FontSize', 13, 365);
}


function incFontSize() {
   var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
   for(i=0;i<p.length;i++) {
      if(p[i].style.fontSize) {
         var s = parseInt(p[i].style.fontSize.replace("px",""));
      } else {
         var s = 11;
      }
      if(s!=max) {
         s += 1;
      }
      p[i].style.fontSize = s+"px"
   }
   setCookie('FontSize',s,365);
}
function decFontSize() {
   var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
   for(i=0;i<p.length;i++) {
      if(p[i].style.fontSize) {
         var s = parseInt(p[i].style.fontSize.replace("px",""));
      } else {
         var s = 11;
      }
      if(s!=min) {
         s -= 1;
      }
      p[i].style.fontSize = s+"px"
   }  
    setCookie('FontSize',s,365);
}
```

The problem with the following code above that on every `post` the text size "flashes". By saying flashes i mean that it first is displayed with the default size (13px) and then is set to the value set by the cookie... which is pretty annoying

So could you please point me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it make the same flash when you choose from the menu, or just when you reload the page?

The original checkCookie code is running on the onload event, which means the page loads and renders before the script that changes the font is run. This means that the original font size will be set first, then your script will run and change it. What you might want to do is house your document in a div that you can set to display:none. Then, when you're done modifying all the font-sizes during the onload event, change it to display:block. That way, you won't see the flash, because the content of the page will be invisible while your code makes the change.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a totally different approach:

First, in your CSS, use em instead of px for setting font sizes.

Then, on the *server side*, when responding to page requests, check the cookie, then set a font size on the body tag, like `<body style="font-size:10px">`. Everything that you sized using em units will be automatically resized relative to the size you've set on the body.

You can also set the font size via JavaScript in response to user actions once the page has loaded, but it would be better to set it server-side otherwise.